# Does CyanogenMod include a kernel?

Tags: cyanogenmod, kernel

I've installed CyanogenMod 10.1 stable for S III LTE (i9305), and noticed that my kernel version is 3.0.64 (I expected it to be 3.4 or something higher).

As I've said in this question, the kernel I had before was also from the 3.0.* line.

Which is quite weird - why is my kernel always staying on that version?

Could it be that CyanogenMod doesn't come with a kernel, but that the kernel is flashed somewhere else?

If not, what's the reason for such a low version number? Is it because my phone isn't all that well-supported? Should I manually flash a new kernel for my phone?

Comment: CyanogenMod generally does have a kernel. Phones are different from x86 PC's though, in that a certain compiled kernel may not support many phones. It would need to be compiled with support for all the hardware in a device. With CM's 3.4 kernel, I'd suspect that it doesn't support the S3. This kind of stuff is fairly common with Samsung phones due to their proprietary hardware and drivers - and their lack of willingness to provide drivers.

Comment: @dotVezz, OK, got it. I suppose you didn't post that as an answer because you aren't sure?

Comment: Indeed. I am sure that CM usually has a custom kernel included, but everything after that is an educated guess at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the repository for that device, I can see that the [specified kernel](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_samsung_i9305/blob/cm-10.2/BoardConfig.mk#L35) is built from source using the source found [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_samsung_smdk4412) and the `cyanogenmod_i9305_defconfig` configuration file.

You can tell that the kernel is not the stock one by going to the terminal app (or from `adb shell`) and typing `uname -a`, which will tell you the build date of the kernel.  If it's the same as the creation date for the whole OS, then you know it's a custom-built kernel just for CM.

The CM11 branch also uses the cm11 branch of this kernel repo...

Comment: Kernel build date is also visible in "Settings -> About Phone", under "Kernel version".

Comment: That's true.. forgot about the UI :)